# RSA decrypt failed

Tags: java, encryption, rsa

I'm trying to use RSA to encrypt and decrypt a json string.Method encrypt is good,also the encryptJSON.
Everthing good until

```
byte[] decryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(encryptedBytes);
```

and e = "javax.cryppto.BadPaddingException:Decrption error"
Here is the source code.

```
public class RSAEncryptJSON {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            String jsonData = "{\"key1\": \"value1\", \"key2\": \"value2\"}";


            KeyPair keyPair = generateKeyPair();


            String encryptedJSON = encryptJSON(jsonData, keyPair.getPublic());
            System.out.println("Encrypted JSON: " + encryptedJSON);


            String decryptedJSON = decryptJSON(encryptedJSON, keyPair.getPrivate());
            System.out.println("Decrypted JSON: " + decryptedJSON);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

   
    private static KeyPair generateKeyPair() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
        return keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
    }

    
    public static String encryptJSON(String jsonData, java.security.PublicKey publicKey) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {
        
        StringBuilder encryptedDataBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        int blockSize = 245; 
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonData.length(); i += blockSize) {
            int endIndex = Math.min(i + blockSize, jsonData.length());
            String encryptedChunk = encrypt(jsonData.substring(i, endIndex), publicKey);
            encryptedDataBuilder.append(encryptedChunk);
        }
        return encryptedDataBuilder.toString();
    }

    
    public static String decryptJSON(String encryptedJSON, java.security.PrivateKey privateKey) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {
        
        StringBuilder decryptedDataBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        int blockSize = 256; 
        for (int i = 0; i < encryptedJSON.length(); i += blockSize) {
            int endIndex = Math.min(i + blockSize, encryptedJSON.length());
            String decryptedChunk = decrypt(encryptedJSON.substring(i, endIndex), privateKey);
            decryptedDataBuilder.append(decryptedChunk);
        }
        return decryptedDataBuilder.toString();
    }

    
    private static String encrypt(String input, java.security.PublicKey publicKey) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {
        javax.crypto.Cipher cipher = javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        cipher.init(javax.crypto.Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
        byte[] encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(input.getBytes());
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encryptedBytes);
    }


    private static String decrypt(String input, java.security.PrivateKey privateKey) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {
        byte[] encryptedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(input);
        javax.crypto.Cipher cipher = javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        cipher.init(javax.crypto.Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
        byte[] decryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(encryptedBytes);
        return new String(decryptedBytes);
    }
}
```

Am I did something wrong?

Comment: You are assuming each of your encrypted data block is 256 bytes long, but as you base64 encode it after encryption each encrypted block is actually 344 char long.

Comment: RSA is usually not used for bulk encryption (encrypting more than one block) .. and you wont find support for it in standard implementation. If you use a symmetric algorithms like AES, you will find that you don't need to implement your own kind of "chunks", as it will work without it just out of the box.

Comment: And not only is 'chunk-wise' RSA nonstandard _and_ inefficient, it is insecure by allowing block replacement and resequencing attacks, but that is offtopic here and belongs on crypto.SX or security.SX. (@Ebbe) Finally, below Java 18 the JVM default charset varies from one system and even run to another, which may result in corruption of non-ASCII chars; JSON _can_ have non-ASCII chars depending on how you create it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.